# Different Communication site versions from production and development tenants

Tags: search, communication-site, release

I have recently been looking into redesigning our companies intranet and wanted to start using Communication sites alongside a home site and hub sites. I started off messing around with a development tenant from Microsoft. Here I saw a new style of communication site with a Search bar at the top and center. However, my live production tenant does not show this.

Any reasons why this would be? Could it just be that the changes haven't been pushed out to my region yet?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Release preferences** setting in the admin center of your dev tenant and Production tenant.

Your dev tenant must be set to get the **Targeted release** under which you get all the latest changes that are not yet ruled out for all the users.

Your Production tenant might be set to **Standart Release** (By Default). So it will not have the latest changes which are not ruled out for everyone.

However, you can get all the latest changes on your Production tenant only for the selected user by setting the Release preferences to **Targeted release for select user**

Reference: [Set up the release option in the admin center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365?view=o365-worldwide#set-up-the-release-option-in-the-admin-center)